# Disjoint covariance matrix estimation

Tags: covariance, multivariate

I have always estimated correlations and variances disjointly and later combine them to construct covariance matrices. Specifically, variances are estimated in a univariate setting (only using the data for each particular asset).

Is there any downside in this approach? Wondering if there is a benefit to estimate variances in a multivariate setting / or if there is any literature on this?

Comment: What is your formula for correlation, if it is not already subsuming the variance, i.e. calculating covariance and just dividing by the univariate variances?

Comment: The potential downside is that you are compounding the estimation errors of two separate procedures when you aggregate them into ones

Comment: Hi: if you google for "estimating covariance matrix in one fell swoop", the first MIT link points to a document that looks pretty good at a quick glance. I'd send the link itself but one is not provided.